# Can you take a look at the code below, It doesn't work and this pops up: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'". Please

Tags: python, string, integer, typeerror

Your teacher has asked you to convert a large number of temperature readings from the Celsius to Fahrenheit scale. They have provided you with the formula to use:
F = C * 9/5 + 32
C is temperature measured in degree Celsius
F is temperature is degree Fahrenheit

my code:

```
c = input("celsius: ") 
f = c*9/5+32
print(c," degrees Celcius is ",f," degrees fahrenheit")
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

f = int(c)*9/5+32

That should work to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit but it is only an approximation...

Comment: Please don't post solutions that you have not personally tested.